# Difficulty in finding the direction ratios of the axial line.

Tags: analytic-geometry, quadrics

I am trying to solve a problem where I need to find the *equation of a right circular cylinder.* The problem tells us that the guiding curve of the cylinder passes through $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ and it mentions nothing more.

Now, I calculated the centre of the above circle through three mentioned points and found the center to be $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3})$ and radius to be $r=\sqrt\frac{2}{3}.$

Now it is necessary to find the *direction ratios* of the axial line to calculate the equation of the right circular cylinder. It is obvious that the axial line passes through the center of the circle which is $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3})$. But, I need one more point that the axial line passes through in order to find it's direction ratios. Then I plan to use the *found direction ratios* in the below equation to find the equation of the cylinder.

$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2+(z-z_1)^2-\frac{\{l(x-x_1)+m(y-y_1)+n(z-z_1)\}^2}{l^2+m^2+n^2}=a^2$  (eq. i),

where,
  $l,m,n$ are the direction ratio's of the axial line,

$(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ are the points through which the axial line passes, which we can take as $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3})$,

$a$ is the radius of the circle(which is $\sqrt \frac{2}{3}$ )

To solve this question I need values of $l,m,n$ which I tried to find but could not. Can anyone guide me clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the points $A(1,0,0), B(0,1,0)$ and $C(0,0,1)$ form an equilateral triangle. The normal vector to the plane in which this triangle lies will possess your desired direction ratios.

First, find

$\vec{AB} = (-1, 1, 0)$

$\vec{BC} = (0, -1, 1)$

And so$$\vec{AB} \times \vec{BC} = (1, 1, 1) =(l,m,n)$$

Comment: It worked (+1) for that!...answer successfully obtained.